# moment of inertia and parallel axis theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

A lamina with density $\delta \left ( x,y \right ) = x^{2}$ has the shape of the disk
$\left \{ \left ( x,y \right )|x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 4 \right \}$.
Find the moment of inertia of the lamina about the line $y=3$.

So I'm having some problem thinking about this question.

Here's what I have so far though,

By the parallel axis theorem:

Evidently, this lamina is symmetrical about the z-axis.

$I_{z'}=I_{z}+M(x^{2}+y^{2}) = \iiint _{w}\left ( x^{2}+y^{2} \right )\delta \left ( x,y,z \right )~dV+{\iiint _w\delta \left ( x,y,z \right )~dV}{(0^{2}+y^{2})}$

And then Mathematica computes

> In[121]:= 
>   Integrate[(x^2 + y^2) (x^2), {z, 0, 0}, {x, -2, 
>      2}, {y, -Sqrt[4 - x^2], 
>      Sqrt[4 - x^2]}] + (Integrate[(x^2), {z, 0, 0}, {x, -2, 
>        2}, {y, -Sqrt[4 - x^2], Sqrt[4 - x^2]}]) (0 + 3^2)
>
> Out[121]= 0

Also, in Polar coordinates

> In[124]:= Integrate[((r Cos[[Theta]])^2 + (r Sin[[Theta]] - 
>         3)^2) (r Cos[[Theta]])^2 r, {z, 0, 0}, {r, 0, 2}, {[Theta], 0,
>      2 [Pi]}]
>
> Out[124]= 0

Could someone kindly clarify if there are anomalies in my though process?